# Loop through multiple data frames and make scatterplots/plots for a list of variables

Tags: r, function, loops, scatter-plot, lapply

I am working on looping through a set of data frames and creating some variables. I ran a regression on the created variables and now want to create a scatterplot or a plot using the y1 and y2 variables and each individual variable in the list of x (y1~x...,y2~x... for all data frames). I have tried several different ways and they all seem to just create multiple of one plot. I tried putting a loop inside the function and in the code below I tried a nested lapply.

```
scat <- function(s) {   

  bkt <- grep("BKT", names(i), invert=T, value = T)

  y1 <- grep("IAS", bkt, value = TRUE)

  y2 <-grep("HEIGHT", bkt, value = TRUE)

  x <- list(grep("ias|ivv", bkt, value = TRUE))

  scat_form <- as.formula(paste0(y1,"~",x)); return(scat.form)
}

  scat_plots <- lapply(myDataList, lapply(x, function(s) plot(scat(s), data=i, main=i)))
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what your data and main arguments are referring to. Is that `lapply()` call inside of a loop? Should you have to specify a data set in the call even though it appears from your example that `lapply()` is being called on a list of data frames and therefore would be applying the `plot(scat(s))` to each of those data frames?

Comment: @D.Mercer I have read in several .csv files and they are stored in a list. With the help of lmo, I was able to create a function to apply a multiple regression to the list of data frames and I modified that code to also do a Durbin Watson test. I now want to use the same list (myDataList), and the same x and y variables to create scatterplots. I was able to make a scatterplot matrix but decided that wasn't what I wanted. The loop I had attempted isn't in this code but I can add that to my post if you would like. The lapply is outside the function and not in a loop.

Comment: A more thorough example with data and the for loop would be helpful. I imagine you could make things easier on yourself by moving the plotting to inside the loop and calling `plot()` on the data frame currently being used to fit your regression model. If it is a multiple regression, are you trying to plot your y against each of the x's used in fitting the model?

Comment: I have been trying to repeat the code I had earlier that had the loop inside the function and the errors I remember without much luck but it went something like this.... ind_scat <- function(c) {bkt <- grep("BKT", names(c), invert=T, value = T);   y1 <- grep("IAS", bkt, value = TRUE);   y2 <-grep("HEIGHT", bkt, value = TRUE);   xx <- grep("ias|ivv", bkt, value = TRUE); for(c in xx){plots<-as.formula(paste0(y1,"~",c))}}

new<-lapply(myDataList,function(c) plot(ind_scat(c),data=c,xlim = c(.001,10),ylim = c(.001,10)))